# How to remove unwanted whitespaces

Tags: html, css

I am practicing html/css by making this website but there are some white spaces to the left and right around the links in list of contents. I have added a sample of html code of how complete list is coded.

I have tried setting the margins and paddings of all elements to zero but nothing is working.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav_bar {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav_bar ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav_bar li {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav_bar">
        <h3>JS DOCUMENTATION</h3>
        <ul class="nav_list">
            <li>
                <a href="page.html#introduction">Introduction</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4s7J.png)

Comment: Yeah sure. Because I don't know what might be causing problem that's is why i added most of css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 1):

You have given the `padding` to the `ul` tag that is the reason why the line did not touch two extreme ends.

just change the `padding` in the `ul` to `0`

Is this what you are looking for ?
I added the color in order to show where the problem occured

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 30%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.nav_bar {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h3 {
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

 ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0;

  margin: 0;
}


 li {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

 li:first-child {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}

 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;

  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color:green;">
  <div class="nav_bar" style="background-color:lightblue;">
    <h3 style="background-color:red;">JS DOCUMENTATION</h3>
    <ul style="background-color:pink;" class="nav_list">
      <li>
        <a href="page.html#introduction">Introduction</a>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are u expecting like this :

**NOTE: CHECK MY ANSWER IN FULL SCREEN MODE**

```
#drop-down{
padding-inline-start:0;  /*use this css */
}
```

HTML:

```
  <ul class="nav_list" id="drop-down">   <!-add id="drop-down" to ul-->
    <li>
     <a href="page.html#introduction">Introduction</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

```css
#drop-down {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav_bar {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav_bar h3 {
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.nav_bar ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav_bar li {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.nav_bar li:first-child {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}

.nav_list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav_bar">
    <h3>JS DOCUMENTATION</h3>
    <ul class="nav_list" id="drop-down">
      <li>
        <a href="page.html#introduction">Introduction</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start padding inline start is experimental and I wouldn't recommend using that in production

Comment: yes, But he want to remove that space( padding-inline-start ) so only I posted @Pete ji

Comment: it worked. plus another solution i set the padding of ul to zero.

Comment: oh k @DaxoBro yes u can do that.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you mean the padding on the `list items` (which you don't currently confiugre in your css), you can do the following;

```css
.nav_list li {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

This will remove the padding on the left and right side side for each `list item` in your `unordered list`.

Also note that in your question, you have not yet set all paddings to 0.

```
.nav_bar ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

If this is not desired behaviour, be sure to set the padding of the `unordered list` to `0` too.

Comment: Would appreciate explanation for downvotes, as this actually solves the OP's problem in a minimal way.

Comment: @DaxoBro specified the 5px padding in the opening post, i assume this is desired behaviour. The question clearly states: `there are some white spaces to the left and right around the links in list of contents`. I'm answering the quesiton directly without making any assumptions.

Comment: Pete you're right i set the padding to 0 and it worked

Comment: I updated my answer to account for the 5px. well spotted.